# Using Javascript to hide a class based on the existence of another class

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to hide a class via Javascript if a different class is present. To explain the situation better, I created a small image sketching the `<div>` situation.

This is the code I'm using:

```
if ($(“.tripdetails” .tripavailable”).length > 0){
document. getElementsByClassName(“.soldoutform”).style.display = “none”;
}
```

The div situation:

```
<div class="tripdetails">
 <div class="tripavailable OR tripunavailable">
  <div class="soldoutform">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

With the OR part, there is either the first or second class name. If it's the first one "tripavailable", the class "soldoutform" should be hidden.

Thank you so much for replying, I really appreciate it! :)

Cheers!

Comment: Disregarding the invalid quotes in your JS code, why not keep using jQuery, which actually supports the short way: `$(".tripavailable .soldoutform").hide();` -- `document.getElementsByClassName()` a) requires the name of the class without a dot b) returns a NodeList c) therefore doesn't have a `style` property.

Comment: Hey Matt - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to ask for more help. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question - *doing so costs you nothing, but helps us.* If no answer was helpful, please post your own and select it with the checkmark to close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

You don't need JS for this. Just use the CSS to your advantage:

```
.tripavailable > .soldoutform {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi IceMetalPunk, and what if the tripavailable and soldoutform classes are both in the same div?

Answer (score 0):

You had an extraneous double-quote character between the two class names.

Note that if the two classes are on the same element *(rather than two different elements, with the `tripavailable` element inside the `tripdetails` element)*, then you would not have a space between the two classnames.

```
if ( $(".tripdetails .tripavailable").length > 0){
  $(".soldoutform").hide();
}
```

---

Also note that your posted code was using problematic quote characters, such as are generated by a word processor. You probably already know that, but it is worth mentioning -- that type of quotes will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

CSS will do the work (you can use display none or visibility hidden)

```
.tripavailable .soldoutform {
   display: none;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you really want to use jquery, then you can do as follow:

```
$(".tripavailable .soldoutform").hide();
```

Or use your original code but remove the extra quote:

```
if ( $(".tripdetails .tripavailable").length > 0){
  $(".soldoutform").hide();
}
```

**EDIT:**

If the class are in the same DIV, just remove the space as follow:

CSS:

```
.tripavailable.soldoutform {
       display: none;
       visibility: hidden;
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".tripavailable.soldoutform").hide();
```

YOUR ORIGINAL JQUERY:

```
if ( $(".tripdetails.tripavailable").length > 0){
  $(".soldoutform").hide();
}
```

Comment: Hi iMac,

Thank you so much for your help. Would you know how to do the above with CSS when both .tripavailable and .soldoutform are in the same div? (I messed up the div explanation above). Thanks mate :)

Comment: @mathijs-de-ruiter sure, just write them together .tripavailable.soldoutform